# Data are not stacking in the queue

Tags: c

I have made a queue of nodes to store the data. 
And the data should be implemented through file I/O.

**In .txt file:**

"Name1"

"Birthday1 (month date)"

"Genre1"

"Name2"

"Birthday2 (month date)"

"Genre2"

(above form is repeated)

Whenever I try to run through the code, it shows some strange characters for Name, Genre, and Birthday. 
Also, same lines are repeated for 14 times. 
I guess the problem has to do with data_in function.

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

typedef struct node {
    char *name, *genre;
    int month, date;

    struct Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct Queue {
    Node *front;
    Node *rear;
    int count;
}Queue;

void queue_init(Queue *queue) {
    //Initializing needed in order to use the queue
    queue->front = queue->rear = NULL;
    queue->count = 0;
}

int isEmpty(Queue *queue) {
    //Check whehter the queue is empty or not
    return (queue->count == 0);
}

void display_node(Node *node) {
    printf("\nName: %s", node->name);
    printf("\nFavorite Genre: %s", node->genre);
    printf("\nBirthday: %d / %d", node->month, node->date);
    printf("\n");
}

void data_in(Queue *queue) {
    Node *now = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("C:\\Users\\brain\\Desktop\\School\\2-2 GWU\\Data Structures and Algorithm\\LAB\\Lab Assignment\\Lab Assignment 3.txt", "r");

    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        char n[100], g[100]; 
        fscanf(f, "%s", &n);
        fscanf(f, "%d %d", &now->month, &now->date);
        fscanf(f, "%s", &g);
        fgets(f); 

        now->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(n)); 
        now->genre = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(g)); 

        now->name = n; 
        now->genre = g; 

        if (isEmpty(queue))
            queue->front = now;
        else
            queue->rear->next = now;
        queue->rear = now; 
        queue->count++;
    }
    fclose(f); 
}

void search(Queue *queue) {
    Node *now = queue->front;

    char c[100], check[100];
    int ch, cnt = 0;

    printf("Which section do you want to search? (Genre or Month): ");
    scanf("%s", &c);

    if (strcmp(c, "Genre") == 0) {
        printf("Type the genre: ");
        scanf("%s", &check);

        for (int i = 0; i < queue->count; i++) {
            if (now != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(now->genre, check)) {
                    display_node(now);
                    now = now->next;
                    cnt = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (cnt == 0) printf("\n.....No results found...");
    }
    else if (strcmp(c, "Month") == 0) {
        printf("Type month as an integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        for (int j = 0; j < queue->count; j++) {
            if (now != NULL) {
                if (now->month == ch) {
                    display_node(now);
                    now = now->next;
                    cnt = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (cnt == 0) printf("\n.....No results found...");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int check = 1; 
    Queue DSA;
    queue_init(&DSA);

    data_in(&DSA);

    while (check == 1) {
        search(&DSA);
        printf("\nDo you want to continue searching? (1 or 0): ");
        scanf("%d", &check);        
        printf("\n============================================================\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: For starters, `now->name = n;` just clobbers the pointer you just assigned to `now->name`. You need to use `strcpy` or some such to copy the characters of the string, not the pointer.

Comment: You don't set `now->next` (to `NULL`) in `data_in`. (Technically not needed because you use `count` to determine if you've reached the end, but this is safer, and it would allow you to simplify your code by replacing `for (int i = 0; i < queue->count; i++)` with `while (now != NULL)`.)

Comment: Despite the name, this is really a *linked-list*, not a *queue*.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are definitely NOT what you want:

```
fscanf(f, "%s", &n);
fscanf(f, "%s", &g);
```

they should read:

```
fscanf(f, "%s", n);
fscanf(f, "%s", g);
```

(notice the removed `&`).

Also, the next line:

```
fscanf(f, "%d %d", &now->month, &now->date);
```

should have a space as the first character of the format string:

```
fscanf(f, " %d %d", &now->month, &now->date);
```